# How to stub a method inside another

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking, stubbing

I'm writing a web app that will send requests to a third-party service to do some calculations, and send it back to the fronted.

Here are the relevant parts for the test I'm trying to writer.

> client.go

```golang
func (c *ClientResponse) GetBankAccounts() (*BankAccounts, *RequestError) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", app.BuildUrl("bank_accounts"), nil)
    params := req.URL.Query()
    params.Add("view", "standard_bank_accounts")
    req.URL.RawQuery = params.Encode()

    c.ClientDo(req)
    if c.Err.Errors != nil {
        return nil, c.Err
    }

    bankAccounts := new(BankAccounts)
    defer c.Response.Body.Close()
    if err := json.NewDecoder(c.Response.Body).Decode(bankAccounts); err != nil {
        return nil, &RequestError{Errors: &Errors{Error{Message: "failed to decode Bank Account response body"}}}
    }

    return bankAccounts, nil
}
```

> helper.go

```golang
type ClientResponse struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Err      *RequestError
}

type ClientI interface {
    ClintDo(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError)
}

func (c *ClientResponse) ClientDo(req *http.Request) {
    //Do some authentication with third-party service

    errResp := *new(RequestError)
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // Here I'm repourposing the third-party service's error response mapping
        errResp.Errors.Error.Message = "internal server error. failed create client.Do"
    }
    c.Response = resp
    c.Err = &errResp
}
```

I only want to test the `GetBankAccounts()` method so I want to stub the  `ClientDo`, but I'm at a loss on how to do that. Here's what I have so far with my test case.

> client_test.go

```golang
type StubClientI interface {
    ClintDo(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError)
}

type StubClientResponse struct {}

func (c *StubClientResponse) ClientDo(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError) {
    return nil, nil
}

func TestGetBankAccounts(t *testing.T) {
    cr := new(ClientResponse)
    accounts, err := cr.GetBankAccounts()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Errors)
    }
    t.Log(accounts)
}
```

The `ClintDo` still pointing to the actual method on the **helper.go**, how can I make it use the on in the test?

---

**Update**:
I've also tried the following and this doesn't work either, it still sends the request to actual third-party service.

> client_test.go

```golang
func TestGetBankAccounts(t *testing.T) {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprint(w, toJson(append(BankAccounts{}.BankAccounts, BankAccount{
            Url:  "https://foo.bar/v2/bank_accounts/1234",
            Name: "Test Bank",
        })))
    }))
    server := httptest.NewServer(mux)
    cr := new(ClientResponse)
    cr.Client = server.Client()
    accounts, err := cr.GetBankAccounts()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Errors)
    }
    t.Log(accounts)
}
```

> helper.go

```golang
type ClientResponse struct {
    Client   *http.Client
    Response *http.Response
    Err      *RequestError
}

type ClientI interface {
    ClintDo(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError)
}

func (c *ClientResponse) ClientDo(req *http.Request) {
    //Do some authentication with third-party service

    errResp := *new(RequestError)
    client := c.Client
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // Here I'm repourposing the third-party service's error response mapping
        errResp.Errors.Error.Message = "internal server error. failed create client.Do"
    }
    c.Response = resp
    c.Err = &errResp
}
```

**Update 2**

I was able to make some progress from @dm03514 's answer but unfortunately, now I'm getting nil pointer exceptions on the test but not on actual code.

> client.go

```golang
func (c *ClientResponse) GetBankAccounts() (*BankAccounts, *RequestError) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", app.BuildUrl("bank_accounts"), nil)
    params := req.URL.Query()
    params.Add("view", "standard_bank_accounts")
    req.URL.RawQuery = params.Encode()

    //cr := new(ClientResponse)
    c.HTTPDoer.ClientDo(req)
    // Panic occurs here
    if c.Err.Errors != nil {
        return nil, c.Err
    }

    bankAccounts := new(BankAccounts)
    defer c.Response.Body.Close()
    if err := json.NewDecoder(c.Response.Body).Decode(bankAccounts); err != nil {
        return nil, &RequestError{Errors: &Errors{Error{Message: "failed to decode Bank Account response body"}}}
    }

    return bankAccounts, nil
}
```

> helper.go

```golang
type ClientResponse struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Err      *RequestError
    HTTPDoer HTTPDoer
}

type HTTPDoer interface {
    //Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError)
    ClientDo(req *http.Request)
}

type ClientI interface {
}

func (c *ClientResponse) ClientDo(req *http.Request) {
  // This method hasn't changed
  ....
}
```

> client_test.go

```golang
type StubDoer struct {
    *ClientResponse
}

func (s *StubDoer) ClientDo(req *http.Request) {
    s.Response = &http.Response{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Body:       nil,
    }
    s.Err = nil
}

func TestGetBankAccounts(t *testing.T) {
    sd := new(StubDoer)
    cr := new(ClientResponse)
    cr.HTTPDoer = HTTPDoer(sd)
    accounts, err := cr.GetBankAccounts()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Errors)
    }
    t.Log(accounts)
}
```

```
=== RUN   TestGetBankAccounts
--- FAIL: TestGetBankAccounts (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x12aae69]
```

Comment: A common approach for stubbing out HTTP requests is to supply the `*http.Client` as an argument with possible fallback to `http.DefaultClient` when the supplied client is nil.  Tests use the [test server client](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server.Client) or a client configured to returned canned responses through a custom [transport](https://godoc.org/net/http#RoundTripper).  This common approach does not stub out the method requests in the question, but perhaps it meets your needs.

Comment: @thwd thanks for the response, does this look similar to what you're suggesting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360256/how-to-implement-stub-in-golang-and-what-difference-between-stub-and-mock

Comment: Or if you could provide an example that would be much appreciated, mainly because most answers for Go testing never works for me. Example, like the one on the sample above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways to achieve this:

- [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20dependency%20injection,object%20is%20called%20a%20service.) using interfaces (your example)
- Custom `http.Transport`, which has a hook you can override in your unit tests

It looks like you're close on the interface approach, and are lacking an explicit way to configure the concrete implementation. Consider an interface similiar to your ClientDo:

```
type HTTPDoer interface {
  Do func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, *RequestError)
}
```

Dependency injection has the caller configure depedencies and pass them into the resources that actually invoke those dependencies. In this case your `ClientResponse` struct would have a reference to a `HTTPDoer`:

```
type ClientResponse struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Err      *RequestError
    HTTPDoer HTTPDoer
}
```

This allows the caller to configure the concrete implementation that `ClientResponse` will invoke. In production this will be the actual `http.Client` but in test it could be anything that implements the `Do` function.

```
type StubDoer struct {}

func (s *StubDoer) Do(....)
```

The unit test could configure the `StubDoer`, then invoke `GetBankAccounts` and then make asserstion:

```
sd := &StubDoer{...}
cr := ClientResponse{
   HTTPDoer: sd,
}
accounts, err := cr.GetBankAccounts()
// assertions
```

The reason it's called Dependency Injection is that the caller initializes the resource (`StubDoer`) and then provides that resource to the target (`ClientResponse`). `ClientResponse` knows nothing about the concrete implementation of `HTTPDoer`, only that it adheres to the interface!

---

I [wrote a blog post](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/you-are-going-to-need-it-using-interfaces-and-dependency-injection-to-future-proof-your-designs-2cf6f58db192) that details dependency injection in the context of unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. I was able to make some headway with this but now I'm getting nil pointer exception on the testes but not in the actual method. I've updated the post with the new version of the code.

Comment: I've managed to fix that, it was me being silly and not returning the response and instead assigning to the receiver passed in. Now I've changed the method signature to the one you've and it's working.